# Over looping (Cout) in C++

Tags: c++, cout, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
char hold;
string name;
char num1;
char num2;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello!\n";
    cout << "Tell me your name?: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Well well well, if it isn't "<< name << "!\n";
    cout << "Enter a NUMBER " << name << ": ";
    cin >> num1;
    while(!isdigit(num1)) {
        cout << "Enter a NUMBER " << name << ": ";
        cin >> num1;    
    }
    cin >> hold;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

The problem is, it is overlooping the cout. How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: The usual error: Not checking the result of formatted inputs and not maintaining the stream state.

Comment: Note: You should be able to copy the console output and integrate it into the question.

Comment: crashmstr, Im pretty new to C++, so Im just getting the hang of it. 
And Dieter, could you explain more please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use `std::stringstream` (note: include `sstream`)

```
    int getNumber()
    {
        std::string line;
        int i;
        while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            if (ss >> i)
            {
               if (ss.eof())
               {
                  break;
               }
            }
            std::cout << "Please re-enter your input as a number" << std::endl;
        }
        return i;  
     }
```

This replaces your while loop, and you make the call after asking for a number as you already figured out how to do.

Comment: Not much better: It will return an uninitialized i, if the first getline fails.

Comment: @DieterLücking: How would it fail on cin? Just curious.. its not obvious to me

Comment: `echo "" | test` will make it fail

Comment: @DieterLücking: When would that happen in the course of OP's program? I would think the `cin` before the loop would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a shortened version of the original attempt. However, as with the original, it only checks a single character.

If I changed num1 to be an int then i'd need to check whether the input was valid as @Dieter Lucking mentioned.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char num1;
    do {
        cout << "\nEnter a number: ";
        cin >> num1
    } while(!isdigit(num1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a variation on staticx's solution, which will pass Dieter Lücking's `echo "" | test` line.

I use an istringstream and get input until no more standard input or I get valid input. I pushed it all into a templated `Get` function that can be used for any type; you just need to give it a prompt for the user:

#### Get() function

```
template<typename T>
void Get(T& toSet, std::string prompt) // read from cin
{
    std::string nextIn;
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin >> std::ws, nextIn);
    istringstream inStream(nextIn);
    while(cin && !(inStream >> toSet))
    {
        inStream.clear();
        cout << "Invalid Input. Try again.\n" << prompt;
        getline(cin >> std::ws, nextIn);
        inStream.str(nextIn);   
    }
    if (!cin)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to get proper input. Exiting";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
int myNumber = 0;
Get(myNumber, "Please input a number:");
```

---

### Full code:

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/0XodZ0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void Get(T& toSet, std::string prompt) // read from cin
{
    std::string nextIn;
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin >> std::ws, nextIn);
    istringstream inStream(nextIn);
    while(cin && !(inStream >> toSet))
    {
        inStream.clear();
        cout << "Invalid Input. Try again.\n" << prompt;
        getline(cin >> std::ws, nextIn);
        inStream.str(nextIn);   
    }
    if (!cin)
    {
        cerr << "\nFailed to get proper input. Exiting\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    string name;
    int num1 = -1;
    cout << "\nHello!\n";
    Get(name, "\nTell me your name?:");
    cout << "\nWell well well, if it isn't "<< name << "!\n";
    Get(num1, std::string("\nEnter a NUMBER, ") + name + ": ");
    cout << "\nYou entered number: " << num1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```